# Balance from ethereum accounts on geth disappears

Tags: go-ethereum, private-blockchain, metamask, golang

I have geth private network with 3 accounts A, B and C.
each account has 100, 200 and 300 ether balance

I connected to this network from Metamask and Transferred the balance of 50 eth from account A to B "Successfully" and it shows in the completed transactions in Matamask. (Result is A: 50, B: 250 C: 300)

Now, when i disconnect from Metamask and stop my geth network AND reconnect again using the geth console, it does not give the expected balance (Result is A: 50, B: 250 C: 300)

However, when i keep the mining in running in background, it shows the expected balance. Can someone please explain why is this behavior.

Comment: Could be a MetaMask bug. Does re-selecting the network on MetaMask refresh the balances after reconnecting to geth?

Comment: yes it does show up in Metamask on refresh, post I reconnect to geth console (and start mining in backgound)

Comment: I removed metamask layer, while deploying smart contracts to the geth pvt network. I did connect to pvt geth network from Remix IDE. couple of deployments as well as Txs were successful to the blockchain from Remix. However problem is whatever balance i had earned in all of my accounts got disappeared all of a sudden. Previously, I was having respective 12, 0.5 and 2 ETH, of balance on my pvt geth accounts, now all three accounts have zero balance. Is there any specific reason for balance being disappeared